# How can I return unordered_map with a hash function to something expecting just `unordered_map<string, string>`

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I want to implement an `unordered_map<string, string>` that ignores case in the keys. My code looks like:

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> noCaseMap()
    {
        struct hasher {
            std::size_t operator()(const std::string& key) const {
                return std::hash<std::string>{}(toLower(key));
            }
        };
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, hasher> ret;
        return ret;
    }
```

but XCode flags the return statement with this error:

```
foo.cpp:181:20 No viable conversion from returned value of type 'unordered_map<[2 * ...], hasher>' to function return type 'unordered_map<[2 * ...], (default) std::hash<std::string>>'
```

I tried casting `ret` to `<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>>`, but XCode wasn't having it.

I tried making my hasher a subclass of `std::hash<std::string>` but that made no difference.

---

Edit: this is a slight oversimplification of the problem; I know I also have to implement a case-insensitive `equal_to()` functor as well.

Comment: You can't. There's a reason it's part of the type: efficiency. What you can do is e.g. store everything lowercase.

Comment: Yes, I had an earlier implementation that did store everything lower case, but I want to return this struct to client code that might not convert the key to lower case before reading from the map.

Comment: But if you cant, you can't.  Make your comment an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Why not declare `hasher` at namespace scope and adjust the return type? Also note that `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, hasher>` probably doesn't do what you want: this just uses a worse hash function, but it doesn't change anything about key equality. Inserting values for `"a"` and `"A"` into your map will still result in 2 entries, but those 2 entries will always result in a hash collision.

Comment: Yes, the next step after getting the hasher to work would have been to get a case-insensitive comparator to work. But I got stuck at the hasher and decided to go ahead and post.

Comment: you can return a `std::unordered_map<Foo, std::string>` where `Foo` can be constructed from a string and stores a lower case string. When the user then looks up `the_map["AsDf"]` then their string will be converted to lower case

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number although you will have to be careful about how Foo can be constructed, because `char[5] -> std::string -> Foo` isn't a legal conversion sequence for `the_map["AsDf"]`

Comment: Yes, another thought I had was to subclass `unordered_map` with a variant that converted to lowercase on all puts and gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There's a reason it's part of the type: efficiency. What you can do is e.g. store everything lowercase. If you need both lowercase and case-preserving, you might need two maps; but, at this point, I'd consider requesting an interface change.